# Shorten loop to list comprehension with multiple for's and ifs/elifs

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have this code, where the dictionary keys are functions and the values are lists which contains keywords. It searches through a listed `t` and it sees if it's in a list from the values of the dictionary. If it is, then it runs the function [key] of that value. If not, it runs the `NowThis` function. The `count` variable is there just so that in the case `t` being `'hello hi'`.

```
dct = {doThis:['hi','hello'],
       doThat:['bye','goodbye']}

t = 'hi there' # or 'test'|'goodbye'|'hello hi'
count=0
for listValue in t.split():
    if count > 1 or count < 0:
        break
    elif listValue in [n for v in dct.values() for n in v]:
        for key,vl in dct.iteritems():
            if listValue in vl:
                key()
                count+=1
    elif count==0:
        nowThis()
        count -=1
```

I did have a previous version of this code where it was just for if for if, and I was easily able to turn that into a list comprehension:

```
[key() for listValue in t.split() if listValue in [n for v in dct.values() for n in v] for key,vl in dct.iteritems() if listValue in vl]
```

However, I am having trouble turning the current code into something like that list comprehension.

Comment: Are you sure you want to sacrifice code readability over a complex list comprehension?

Comment: if you don't use the return value of `key` you shouldn't create a listcomp to perform the loop.

Comment: I haven't looked closely at your code, but the dictionary looks back-to-front. Why don't you make the 'hi', 'hello', etc string the keys, with your functions as the values?

Comment: The list comprehension isn't going to be any faster. The benefit of a list comprehension lies in the fact that you can use a bare expression where `map` would require it to be wrapped in a user-defined function. Compare `[x['foo']['bar] for x in mylist]` with `map(lambda x: x['foo']['bar'], mylist)`.

Comment: Also, you aren't actually building a list with your `for` loop, so the list comprehension adds *more* overhead by having to construct a list.

Comment: Your current code breaks out of the `for listValue in t.split():` loop after it's processed the 1st item. So why bother having a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been explained in the comments there is no benefit in using a list comprehension here. It would actually be slower, since you'd be creating a list you don't actually want. Also, it is considered poor design to use a list comp purely for its side effects.

As I mentioned in the comments, your dictionary design is the wrong way around, so you aren't getting the benefits of using a dictionary, i.e., a dict can quickly test if a key is present, and it can quickly retrieve the value associated with a key.

Assuming your  current code does what you want, here's a better way to write it.

```
def do_this():
    print 'Do This!\n'

def do_that():
    print 'Do That!\n'

def now_this():
    print 'Now This!\n'

dct = {
    'hi': do_this,
    'hello':  do_this,
    'bye': do_that,
    'goodbye': do_that,
}

data = ('hi there', 'python', 'goodbye hello', '')
for t in data:
    v = t.split(None, 1)[0] if t else ''
    print [t, v]
    dct.get(v, now_this)()
```

**output**

```
['hi there', 'hi']
Do This!

['python', 'python']
Now This!

['goodbye hello', 'goodbye']
Do That!

['', '']
Now This!
```

Here's a more compact version of that `for` loop without the `print` statements:

```
for t in data:
    dct.get(t.split(None, 1)[0] if t else '', now_this)()
```

We use a conditional expression (`t.split(None, 1)[0] if t else ''`) so we can handle when `t` is an empty string. Here's an alternative version that's less readable. :)

```
for t in data:
    dct.get((t.split(None, 1) or [''])[0], now_this)()
```

If you can *guarantee* that `t` will never be an empty string, then you can use the simple version:

```
for t in data:
    dct.get(t.split(None, 1)[0], now_this)()
```